ICDeviceBrowser fails to find any devices after iOS 18 update
I have an app that uses the ImageCaptureCore's ICDeviceBrowser to find and connect to external digital cameras. Prior to iOS 18 this worked just fine, the device browser would start up and find any cameras connected via USB. However since the update the device browser fails to ever detect any connected device or to trigger any delegate events at all after browser start.
I noticed that the Contents authorization in iOS 18 is undetermined, where in previous iOS versions it would default to authorized. I tried to resolve this by requesting authorization, however this immediately returns denied without ever having prompted the app user for permission. I do have the Camera Privacy Usage description setup, and also am able to request permission for the iOS camera successfully.
How can I successfully request contents authorization via ICC or otherwise?
Or are there alternative Apple libraries I can use for finding and connecting to external digital cameras on iOS?

I had the same problem. It resolved after selecting USB under the hardware section in the Signing & Capabilities -> App Sandbox. Everything's back to normal now. 
